# Trying to overlap two same size JPanels in a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I am trying to overlap two same size JPanels (here 'pseudo' and ' svg'). JPanel pseudo is behind svg. The JButton is supposed to move pseudo in front of svg. The result is that centerPanel.moveToFront(pseudo) does not work. Did I miss something?

```
        centerPanel = new JLayeredPane();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        centerPanel.add(pseudo, BorderLayout.CENTER, -1);
        centerPanel.add(svg, BorderLayout.CENTER, 0);

        view3D = new JButton("View 3D");

        view3D.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                centerPanel.moveToFront(pseudo);
            }
        });
```

Comment: *"Did I miss something?"* The [mcve] that demonstrates your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The JButton is supposed to move pseudo in front of svg

Then you should be using a `CardLayout`. A `CardLayout` is a layout manager that lets 2 (or more) components occupy the same space, but only one component is visible at a time.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and a working example to get you started

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And the new code is:

```
        JPanel cardsPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        cardsPanel.add(svg, "svgPanel");
        cardsPanel.add(pseudo, "pseudo");

        view3D = new JButton("View 3D");

        view3D.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardsPanel.getLayout());
                    cl.show(cardsPanel, "pseudo");
                }
            }
        });
```